# Docker download failure management

Tags: docker, disk

I tried to pull a big docker image, but it failed cause of disk space. However, some download and extracting had already been proceed (like few gigabytes), so I was wondering where those data goes.

Any Ideas?

Futhermore, is it possible to restart the pull where it failed or I have to restart from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

storage for docker images are normally in a directory like `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/`. It will depend on your version, your storage driver, your distro, etc.

You can find the correct values on your system with `docker image inspect`, and then looking for `GraphDriver.Data` properties.

Since images are broken up into layers, you absolutely can pick up where you left off, after a failed `docker pull`.

You may also wish to look into [docker system prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)